# How can you run Genshin Impact in borderless windowed mode?

Tags: genshin-impact

The menu video settings only allow for either fullscreen or windowed, but not borderless fullscreen or windowed fullscreen, which would be nice for me as I run a dual monitor setup. It is annoying to have to alt-tab out to the browser which then causes the game to minimize.

How can you run Genshin Impact in borderless windowed mode?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**A non-Steam solution I've found**:

1. Navigate to the `C:\Program Files\Genshin Impact\Genshin Impact Game` path and locate the GenshinImpact.exe executable.
2. Right-click to create a Shortcut to the executable.
3. Right-click the Shortcut to open its properties
4. In the `Target` field, append the string `-popupwindow` after whatever is currently inside the box.

[image]

5. Whenever you launch using the shortcut it should now start Genshin Impact in borderless windowed mode.
6. Make sure to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> when the game has launched.

Comment: Ahh, I did not think of doing this. Good idea!

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. and the game is still locked to full screen

Comment: @Rapitor Press Alt+Enter when you start the game.

Comment: Does not work.
I mean it KINDA does. Window has a title bar still, so... nope!
Any other ideas?

Comment: @GMRod This works fine for me as of Hu Tao's banner releasing. Are you sure you've tried both the Steam and Non-Steam options here? Also check to see that you have launched using the shortcut and not the original .exe file

Answer (score 5):

This isn't available in the game to my knowledge, but there is a workaround that the community has found that may work for you. If you have **Steam** installed on your PC:

1. Open **Steam.**
2. Click **"Games**" in the top left corner, and in the submenu select "**Add a Non-Steam Game**."

[image: Add a NonSteam Game]

3. A window will pop up, but don't select the game from there. Instead, click on "**Browse.**"

[image]

4. Navigate to your Genshin Impact root folder. Find the "Genshin Impact Game" folder. Inside, select **Genshinimpact.exe**, then hit "**Open**" and hit "**Add Selected Programs**".
5. From your Steam library, right-click "**GenshinImpact**", then click "**Browse**."
6. Click "**Set Launch Options**" and add the line **"-popupwindow."** Hit "**OK**."
7. Launch the game. If it starts the game in fullscreen, hold **Alt + Enter** to set it to borderless window mode.

([Source](https://forums.mihoyo.com/genshin/article/17838))

Comment: Skipping the Steam process, could you do the same thing with the executable in the game files directly?